# Bad ADC AC Performance

Tags: ac, adc, rectifier

I'm using a MCU ADC, PIC18F26K22, to sample and calculate a RMS value of a sine wave that is rectified by the full precision rectifying circuit in the schematic below. This ADC has 10 bits and I'm sampling at 50 kHz. The signal is 2 kHz and at the ADC input has 700mVp. This voltage was measured with a digital oscilloscope.

I already did the compensation for Gain and Offset errors, using DC voltages and a very good quality multi-meter, but when I'm sampling this sine wave I'm having a very poor accuracy in the results, for instance, in 700mVp Sin Wave the ADC is sampling peak values of ~620mV. I'm using the internal voltage reference of 2.048V, which guarantees a low error.

So, I'm really clueless about what could be done to solve this, I already increased the acquisition time, with the cost of reducing the sampling frequency, but still the voltage peak values do not change.

What is the cause of the incorrect peak voltage? How can I fix this problem?

[image: Full Wave Rectifier]

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do the RMS-DC in the digital domain?

Comment: Not a very strong one, in this project i have already the MCU available and a precision rectifier is a circuit that is cheap and doable with basic resources. The other solutions i found was  RMS-TO-DC IC , but their price is not so great, its all from 5$ - 6$. Is this the solution you were having in mind ? If you have any others, i would like to know. Thank you

Comment: Regarding the ADC performance: A poor circuit layout, improper routing/separation of analog/digital MCCU/ADC powering, bad grounding, presence of switching loads and regulators can be raise the noise level, thus reducing the ENOB (Effective Number of Bits) of ADC. For example, a 12 bit ADC can, really works as 8 bit. Also, there is also difference between accuracy and precision.

Comment: Check the silly stuff first: (1) IC3-A has to swing negative as it's in inverting mode. What's the chip's negative supply rail? (2) Can you measure the negative DC voltage after the upper diode?

Comment: @Dirceu , the MCU, voltage regulators and power supply are well conditioned in a PCB. The Precision Rectifier  i'm testing in a breadboard.  Of course breadboards are very problematic, but  I'm not having this performance issues reading DC values in the same board. However i will try to minimize any source of noise in the breadboard and i will let you know if any improvements where accomplished.

Comment: @Transistor, the Rectifier is a text-book classic , you will find it all over in internet in even in Sedra, is the negative rail is -3.3v. I think its not worth to describe the function of the circuit, because it works, is tested and won't contribute to the discuss about the performance of the ADC, i only showed to prove that the signal in ADC comes from a very low impedance source.

Comment: Start with the obvious. The ADC says you're only giving it 620 mV. Is this true? That is, what does the ADC input look like on a scope?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, i'm sorry i didn't made it clear, i know that the signal has a a peak of 700mVp because i'm measuring it with an oscilloscope at the input of the ADC channel. I edited the question.

Comment: R13 should go to the SINEWAVE input, not pin 4 of IC3-A.